# Return dropdownlist to initially selected value

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm creating a create-read-edit-delete interface.

I have a dynamically populated `dropdownlist`, `ddl_Status` which on page load is set to select a particular value. The dropdownlist is then disabled.

If the user clicks "Edit" then I enable the dropdownlist. The user can then change the selection.

If the user clicks "Cancel" I want to return the dropdownlist to it's initial selection and then disable it. If I use `ddl_Status.SelectedValue` I get the value that the user has selected.

In javascript I would use `ddl_Status.defaultValue` but I can't find an equivalent in .NET.  I'm considering using a hidden field value to store the initial value, but this just seems clumsy.

Comment: could you please post your code? thanks !

Comment: The code is mostly irrelevant.   What I'm looking at is `ddl_Status.SelectedValue = ddl_Status.SelectedValue` which is obviously nonsense.

Answer (score 1):

When populating your dropdown list, store the default value in an asp hidden field (hdn_DefaultValue), when the user clicks "cancel": ddl_Status.selectedValue = hdn_DefaultValue.

Comment: Thanks, I mentioned trying to avoid doing this in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You could store `ddl_Status.SelectedIndex` in a variable right after loading the page and restore it every time the user clicks "Cancel". Of course this only works if there aren't any changes made to the items.

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking for something built in.